# Get Values DataFrame in R

Tags: r

I have the following date.frame. How do I get only the data without the column name?

```
Date P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10
196  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

I only need to get the 2: 8 position value but without the column name.. I tried that way but I could not

```
c(dfSim[,2:8])
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you want to do. Do you want to remove the column names from a data frame permanently? Or do you just want to print it without column names? And do you want to keep the data as a data.frame, or as a vector (as you've shown in your example)?

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
# c(dfSim[2:8,]),
```

It shows only the values in the specified margin and the column appears separately on top of these values

Comment: That would subset by rows, not columns as the asker wants, and is otherwise identical to the code they posted that didn't work